# Savon: Array of XML tags

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

I'm using [Savon](https://rubygems.org/gems/savon) for SOAP requests and in some place of the SOAP request XML, I need to generate this piece of code:

```
<content>
  <item a="1" b="0"/>
  <item a="2" b="0"/>
  <item a="3" b="0"/>
</content>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I think you're going to need to explain some more.  Try showing what you've tried and how it didn't work, people will probably help you out more.

Comment: added more information to the question so others don't vote it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution.

```
soap.body = {  
    #... other tags  
    "content" => {  
        "item" => ["", "", ""],  
        :attributes! => {  
            "item" => {  
                "a" => ["1", "2", "3"],  
                "b" => ["0", "0", "0"]  
            }  
        }  
    }
    #... other tags    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Savon v0.9.7](https://rubygems.org/gems/savon/versions/0.9.7) comes with improved support for Builder and I would suggest to use it instead of trying to force attributes via Hashes, because it's way more readable:

```
soap.body do |xml|
  xml.content do
    xml.item(:a => "1", :b => "0")
    xml.item(:a => "2", :b => "0")
    xml.item(:a => "3", :b => "0")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
def content
  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
  xml.content do
    xml.item(:a => "1", :b => "0")
    xml.item(:a => "2", :b => "0")
    xml.item(:a => "3", :b => "0")
  end
end
```

Comment: No, no, I need something to put inside soap.body. Because I already have a structured xml using hashes.

Comment: Then please add the structure you currently have, or the structure that you need to the question so it can be answered.