# Savon | How to put different attributes in array of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, savon

I'm using Savon gem to connect with a SOAP service. My problem is that I need to send an array of items with different attribute on each key.

I have looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751682/how-to-use-objects-with-xsitypes-in-savon?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001957/savon-array-of-xml-tags?rq=1)

What I'm trying to get as XML is:

```
<Order>
  <OrderItems>
    <OrderItem code="AJF">
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem code="BUD">
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </OrderItem>
  </OrderItems>
</Order>
```

What I'm sending as message is:

```
{Order: {
  OrderItems: {
    OrderItem: [{
      Quantity: 1,
      attributes!: { code: "AJF"}
    },{
      Quantity: 1,
      attributes!: { code: "BUD"}
    }]
  }
}}
```

What I'm getting is:

```
<Order>
  <OrderItems>
    <OrderItem>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </OrderItem>
  </OrderItems>
</Order>
```

I've searched it but haven't found anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212367/how-do-you-add-nested-attributes-in-savon-2-3?rq=1).

The hash has to be like this:

```
{Order: {
  OrderItems: {
    OrderItem: [{
      Quantity: 1,
      :'@code' => "AJF"}
    },{
      Quantity: 1,
      :'@code' => "BUD"}
    }]
  }
}}
```